# How can one prevent the title tooltip from being shown, but allow :hover to still be used?

Tags: html, css, reddit

Currently working with a reddit theme, which only allows CSS to be changed. In these themes, there are text flairs which we have replaced with background images. When you hover over one, it shows a tooltip with the text. This is a default reddit feature and cannot be changed.

What we're trying to do is display the title attribute in a much cleaner way. We really dont have any way of doing this other than using `:hover:after`, but setting `pointer-events` to `none` prevents `:hover` from showing up, presumably because `pointer-events` makes the element click-through.

Is there any way to bypass this and use our `:hover` tag?

Comment: Could you provide us the code of one of these flairs? 

It it's an img element and the attribute is called title, I don't think there would be any CSS-only solution to hide it.

Comment: @rnndbn It's a <span> with the background set as an image from a spritesheet. 
I've found a solution unique to reddit, but I'll leave this question up in case someone has a similar request unrelated to my code. 

I'm just curious as to if there's a way this can be done without extremely hacky code